# Elementos alineados en un form

Tags: bootstrap

Estoy usando `bootstrap 4.5` y en el formulario tengo tres elementos que deben estar alineados de manera horizontal. Sin embargo los dos primeros están muy separados y el botón está junto a input-text.
Y que en la versión para moviles el botón esté en otra línea.

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" value="Ingrese busqueda">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor" name="buscar" placeholder="valor">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</form>
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

para esto te pueden servir 2 clases que se encuentran dentro de la documentación de bootstrap, son las siguientes:

-row
-col

Con ellas puedes alinear las etiquetas dentro de tu proyecto, para que queden de la siguiente forma.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-6">
    <button ID="btnDisponible" CssClass="btn btn-success text-white w-100 font-weight-bold">Disponible</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-6">
    <button ID="btnPeddos" CssClass="btn btn-success text-white w-100 font-weight-bold">Pedidos</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adicional a eso, puedes revisar el tamaño que va a ocupar tu etiqueta con las clases, cada una de ellas ajusta el tamaño según las proporciones de la pantalla.

- col-lg-
- col-md-
- col-sm-
- col-xs-

Te adjunto un link donde puedes revisar más documentación.

[Link pagina de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Saludos.

Comment: Justo ya lo estaba haciendo con `form-inline`. Gracias.

Comment: Justo ya lo estaba haciendo con `form-inline`. Gracias.